# Flutter Animated Cross Fade overflow on transition

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a button component that I want to show a loading spinner when it is told the component is loading. I animate between the loading and non loading states using `AnimatedCrossFade`.

My problem is: I get an overflow error when returning back to the original "non-loading" state. I know this is to do with the `Row` and having different sized widgets, but I have tried many combinations of flex widgets etc. and none work. I have also tried using `Offstage` on the change of `this.isLoading`. However that didn't work either (and basically defeated the point of the animator).

Solutions that do solve the overflow issue, cause the button to become its maximum possible width which I don't want all the time. The button needs to be able to take up the smallest amount of space it requires.

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: isLoading ? () => null : () => onPressed(),
        style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(primaryColour)),
        child: AnimatedCrossFade(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          crossFadeState:
              isLoading ? CrossFadeState.showSecond : CrossFadeState.showFirst,
          firstChild: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 10.0),
            child: this.child,
          ),
          secondChild: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              this.childWhenLoading,
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                  width: 20,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colours.white),
                    backgroundColor: primaryColour,
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flutter team has addressed this here: https://youtu.be/PGK2UUAyE54?t=85.

I was facing this same issue and this worked for me:

```dart
AnimatedCrossFade(
  // ... Other arguments

  layoutBuilder: (topChild, topKey, bottomChild, bottomKey) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Positioned(
          key: bottomChildKey,
          top: 0,
          child: bottomChild,
        ),
        Positioned(
          key: topChildKey,
          child: topChild,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  }
),
```